# Create type from library default export

Tags: typescript

I am using OpenLayers with a definition file containing :

```
// Type definitions for ol 4.6
// Project: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/master/package#readme
// Definitions by: Yair Tawil <https://github.com/yairtawil>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
import * as ol from 'openlayers';

export default ol;
```

I would like to type my variables with the correct types (obviously), and until now we were doing

```
import Map from 'ol/map';
...
olMap: Map;
```

Now, I am trying to change that to something like

```
import * as OpenLayers from 'ol';
...
// want to do this
olMap: OpenLayers.Map;
// But can only do this
olMap: OpenLayers.default.Map;
```

Is there a way to declare the default export as a type to be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this a default import then use the default import syntax and things will work as expected:

```
import OpenLayers from 'ol';
```

You can get the type of default and use it like so (but I do recommend the first option):

```
import * as OpenLayers from 'ol';
type ol = typeof OpenLayers.default
let olMap: ol.Map;
```

Comment: So simple ... Thank you, I'm marking it as validated in a couple of minutes !